# Wait until UI has updated before removing UIActivityIndicator

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch, uiactivityindicatorview

I am having an issue with an iPad app I am developing. I have the following code:

```
CFTimeInterval startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();

[self showSpinnerWithMessage:@"Loading settings..."]; // Shows a UIActivityIndicator on screen

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^
{
    //Updating items on screen here
    [label1 setText:@"Test1"];
    [label2 setText:@"Test3"];
    //...

    CFTimeInterval difference = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime;

    if (difference < MINIMUM_INDICATOR_SECONDS)
    {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:MINIMUM_INDICATOR_SECONDS - difference];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
    {
        [self removeSpinner]; // Removes UIActivityIndicator from screen
    });
};
```

The problem is that sometimes the UI takes a while to update, and in these particular instances the spinner (UIActivityIndicator) goes away before the UI has actually updated. I realize this is because the items on screen do not actually update until the next run loop so my question is, how can make my `[self removeSpinner]` call wait until the UI has updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the UI-updating code in the block with `removeSpinner`.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
{
    [label1 setText:@"Test1"];
    [label2 setText:@"Test3"];
    [self removeSpinner]; // Removes UIActivityIndicator from screen
});
```

Comment: Husker is right. Move any UI updating into the main queue. Not sure if you do any other intensive UI updating because you did not provide the full code, but you can also do [self performSelecter:@selectory(removeSpinner) afterDelay:0], if you want the removeSpinner to happen in the next runloop.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `[self.view setNeedsDisplay];` just before the `[self removeSpinner]`.